# Google app engine shading consistency

Tags: python, google-app-engine, concurrency, transactions

I'm having problems with Google App Engine attempts to ensure strong constancy when aggregating shard-ed entities. I originally was under the assumption that batch "gets" by keys ensured that read's were up to date, but have since learned that that is incorrect. Now I'm confused as to how I can achieve strong constancy.

Here's what I'm trying to do: 
I'm building an "game" in which users vote in polls. The voting takes place rapidly (about once per user minute), so I believe a shading technique is necessary to ensure users are not bottle-necked when writing their votes. When a user places a vote, a poll entity is read to make sure that the poll is still running, then assuming the writing of the vote to the shard is successful, the user should receive notification that their vote was counted (on the returned page). After a poll ends, the shards are assembled and computations are done based on the votes of each user; the results are then displayed.

It is important that a user's vote, which received confirmation, is actually seen during the shard aggregation. It's ok if the server rejects a user's vote (especially if its near the end of polling), but they should receive a failure notification. I'm worried that with GAE's eventual consistency assurances that cases may arise (when using only basic shading) in which a user successfully writes their vote to a shard (and get success notification), but the accumulator does not yet see the update and does not count that user vote in the final tally.

It it possible to prevent this? Do I even need to worry about this in practice?

Thanks!

Comment: You said  **I originally was under the assumption that batch "gets" by keys ensured that read's were up to date, but have since learned that that is incorrect.**   what leads you to believe this.  gets by Key are consistent, queries without using an ancestor won't be consistent.

Comment: Can you show the code for how you are issuing your get operations?  Maybe they aren't actually get by key operations (which should be consistent).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to achieve real-time results, then use [memcache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/functions).  The incr() method should be of particular interest to your voting game.  You can write the results to the datastore on a much less frequent basis (say, every 100 votes and again at the end of voting) so your performance will be much better.  You may even be able to avoid sharding this way.